# Separate results by comma in django

Tags: python, django, templates

how would you separate results in Django template?

I have a category model as below

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    category_meta = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    category_description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

this is how i print it in my template

```
<h3 class="movie-items-listing">{% for category in movie.movie_category.all |join:", " %}{{ category }}{% endfor %}</h3>
```

and this is the error i get

> TemplateSyntaxError at /movies/ 'for' statements should use the format
>   'for x in y': for category in movie.movie_category.all |join:", "

Now when I wanna list these, they show up like category 1 category 2

I tried to use template filters to separate these but keep having errors.

Comment: Can you show your current template language?

Comment: Can you post what errors are you having?

Comment: I just did along with my template code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `join` template filter incorrectly. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join)

Try this

```
{{ movie.movie_category.all|join:", " }}
```

Your template should look like this

```
<h3 class="movie-items-listing">{{ movie.movie_category.all|join:", " }}</h3>
```

Comment: I did, its giving me errors - ive updated my code above